# Scanner not reading Next() or NextLine() immediately

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have the following code

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter A name");
String aString = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.print(aString);
System.out.print("Enter A message");
String bString = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.print(bString);
```

Every time I execute this I enter the name then hit enter, nothing happens I enter the name again, nothing happens as well and I enter the name the third time and here we go it prints it. The same thing happens with the second string

I don't understand what could be wrong.

Comment: can you share details of keyboard declaration and method where this code is present

Comment: Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: To get proper answer please [edit] your question and provide proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (a.k.a. [MCVE]) which we could actually debug. For now I can't reproduce described problem using *only* code from question.

Comment: @Sai What terminal do you use?

Comment: @Danon - I use eclipse

Comment: @Sai Run the application in some other terminal, `cmd`/`bash`, or terminal from other IDE like VS Code or IntelliJ. Eclipse terminals are known to have many unintuivive behaviours.

Answer (score -1):

Have you defined `keyboard`? have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp)

Comment: Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);